# Visual Studio 2013 deploy without installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, deployment

I'm developing a Windows app in Visual Studio 2013. When I use the publish feature, it creates a setup to install the app.

I don't want it to create a setup. I want it to build and deploy into a test environment, ready to be executed, without overwriting that environment's app.config. It would be great if I could configure multiple environments and choose which to be deployed.

I found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191495%28v=vs.120%29.aspx but it requires TFS. I wanna do it directly in VS.

To make it more clear, the best solution would me to type F6 - or any other shortcut - and have Visual Studio do the following:

1. build solution
2. copy exe and dlls to a specified folder
3. don't change destination's app.config
4. if possible, copy also source code so that debugger when opened is able to run thru it

It should be able to configure multiple profiles, so that it can send files to multiple test environments.

Comment: here is a general advise, if you want to do it directly in VS, it involves making changes to your project file. basically you have to add custom msbuild project or task to achieve that. or you can use powershell script.

Comment: hmm ok, is there any tutorial explaining how to configure it? I don't mind doing it in XML, I just need to know what to configure.

Comment: Is this a good reference? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx